# JSTL ForEach to tigger inner ForEach at specific count

Tags: loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, foreach, logic, jstl

I have a request that I'm scratching my head over, and I'm hoping someone can help me out.  The client is looking for a sidebar widget that would display related items of a product.  To conserve on vertical space, I have made this area collapsable using a Bootstrap accordion.

After reviewing what I developed, they like the idea but they wish to take it a step farther. The client would like the first three related items always displayed in this related items area, BUT if the items exceed 3, then add the collapsible element below with a toggle button (SHOW MORE).  Problem is, I'm stuck on how the logic would play out in JSTL.

***JSTL:***

```
<ul>
     <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
     <c:forEach var="itemID" items="${sellableGood.relatediItem}">
          <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
          <script>console.log(${count});</script>
          <li>
               <a href="#">${itemID}</a>
          </li>
     </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Here's what I have currently, it's a basic forEach loop that just iterates through all of the related items. I'm puzzled on how I would use the COUNT variable to know when there was more than 3, then put those

in a div within this unordered list. Or is there a way to get the total count before I start outputting the unordered list in the first place?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should help to check if count is greater than 3

```
<c:if test="${count > 3}">
 your logic
</c:if>
```